# Data-structure to store "last 10" data sets?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working with an object Literal to store temporary information to send to clients, it's like a history container for the last 10 sets of data.

So the issue that I', having is figuring out the most efficient way to splice on object as well as push an object in at the start, so basically i have an object, this object has 0 data inside of it.

I then insert values, but what I need to do is when the object reaches 10 keys, I need to pop the last element of the end of object literal, push all keys up and then insert one value at the start.

Take this example object

```
var initializeData = {
    a : {},
    b : {},
    c : {},
    d : {},
    e : {},
    f : {},
    g : {},
    h : {},
    i : {},
    j : {}
}
```

When I insert an element I need **j** to be removed, **i** to become the last element, and **a** to become **b**.

So that the new element becomes **a**.

Can anyone help me solve this issue, I am using node.js but native JavaScript is fine obviously.

---

Working with arrays after advice from replies, this is basically what I am thinking your telling me would be the best solution:

```
function HangoutStack(n)
{
    this._array = new Array(n);
    this.max    = n;
}

HangoutStack.prototype.push = function(hangout)
{
    if(this._array.unshift(hangout) > this.max)
    {
        this._array.pop();
    }
}

HangoutStack.prototype.getAllItems = function()
{
    return this._array;
}
```

Comment: There is no first/last, beginning/end when it comes to JavasScript objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it would be a lot easier to use an array. Then you could use `unshift` to insert from the beginning and `pop` to remove from the end.

**Edit:** Example:

```
var items = []

function addItem(item) {
  items.unshift(item)
  if (items.length > 10) {
    items.pop()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `push`/`shift` instead of `unshift`/`pop`. Depends on which end of the array you prefer the new items to sit at.

Comment: Can you expand with some logic please, some examples would be nice.

Comment: Please check my update, I would like the new items to go to the end ofthe array, but not a major issues as I can flip the array later.

Comment: @RobertPitt Then use `push` and `shift`. The former adds to the end; the latter removes from the start.

Comment: So let's say that i wanted to remove an element out of the array, how would I do that without messing up the array ?

Comment: @RobertPitt `items.splice(index_of_element_you_want_to_remove, 1)` is how you remove an element from an array in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).
Have a look at this [implementation in javascript](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r144/docs/closure_goog_structs_circularbuffer.js.source.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, use an Array.

```
var arr = [];

// adding an item
if (arr.unshift(item) > 10) {
    arr.pop();
}
```

If you need the 'name' of the item, like "a" or "b" in your object example, just wrap each item in another object that contains the name and the object.

Objects in js are like dictionaries -- they have no inherent order to the items. It's just a collection of things. You can try to make up an order (like a through z in your example), but then you have to manage that order yourself when things change. It's just much easier to use an array.

Comment: can you expand on your example with a small function / object with prototypes.